# HTML links are displaying PDFs differently?

Tags: html, pdf, adobe, acrobat, adobe-contribute

I am using Adobe Contribute (HTML editor) to edit a website. I have two links on my page that both link to the same PDF file *type*. However, when the links are clicked they are displaying the PDF differently in IE (the issues does not occur in Chrome): One with the PDF tools and thumbnail sidebar, and the other just as a plain PDF file by itself.

One looks like this:
[image]

The other looks like this:
[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;"><strong>DATE 1 HERE</strong></p>
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;"><a href="documents/file1.pdf">FILE NAME LINK</a></p>
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;"><strong>DATE 2 HERE</strong></p>
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;"><a href="documents/File2.PDF">FILE NAME LINK 2</a></p>
```

What I need is for them both to look like the second one. Any ideas as to what might be causing them to come up differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was a setting within the PDF itself that I needed to change. The following settings fixed my issue.

1. Go to File>Properties
2. In the Document Properties window, select the Initial View tab
3. In the Document Properties window, choose "page only" for Page layout, and check the "hide toolbars" box.
4. In the Document Properties window, click the OK button
5. Go to File>Save
6. Reopen the document

Comment: This "fixed" the case when Adobe Reader is providing the PDF viewing component for the webbrowser. Chrome (and the other browser-provided PDF viewing components) would not honor this setting, but simply display the document without toolbar and panels. So, what these modifications essentially do is make Acrobat/Reader-provided PDF viewing components behave like the dumb browser-provided ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that Chrome and IE will display PDF's differently. It's just how they were designed. I'm not to sure about how to make them look the same, I'm not even sure that you can. But, I think it's just the browsers themselves.

Comment: When tested on IE the two links look different. When tested on Chrome they look the same. So on IE both views are coming up and I'm not sure why. On Chrome there is no issue at all. But why the heck is IE displaying two identical links to PDFs differently?? 

I am thinking it's either a version issue (I recently updated my adobe stuff so maybe the new PDF and the old PDF are having different display issues?) or it's something to do with the PDF file types not being as identical as it seems. I did notice that the one file type is in caps (File2.PDF) and the other is not (file1.pdf).